# Which way is better to implement custom fields in a web application

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a self made web application in `PHP` and `MySQL`. The many different clients using my system would like to augment entities with custom fields. Each client would like to store their own additional data, so this should be done in a dynamic way.

For example *client1* would like to add the "*color*" property to their products, *client2* want a field called "*safety_level*" for their products.

I want a methodology that can be applied not only for products but for users and for any other entities as well.

Here are 2 options I found the optimal, but can't decide which one is the most effective:

***OPTION 1:***
For every entity I make a `[entityname]_customfields` table in which I store the additional field values in 1:1.
e.g.:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|products_custom_fields                       |
+---------------------------------------------+
|product_id (PK and FK related to products.id)|
|safety_level                                 |
|some_other_fields                            |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

**pro:** this table can has no more records than the entity table (in this case the products) which means fewer records and it is quite easy to overview.

**con:** adding new fields or deleting old ones require DDL queries. I don't want to confide DDL to users...not even operators with admin permissions.

***OPTION 2:***
`[entity]_custom_field_values` will have N:1 relations to `[entity]` table. Each row contains the the type of the custom field and the value itself. In this case we need another table which contains the custom field types. e.g.:

custom field values:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|products_custom_field_values                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|custom_field_id                                                       |
|custom_field_type (FK product_custom_field_types.custom_field_type_id)|
|value                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

custom field types:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|products_custom_field_types                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|custom_field_type_id (PK AUTO_INCREMENT)                 |
|product_id (FK related to products.id)                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

***pro:*** managing fields is easy, does not require to alter table structures

***con:*** more records, all kind of custom field values in a big mess...which is not necessary wrong, because that's the point of MySQL, to extract useful data from a big mess. The question is what about efficiency and performance?

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>**Note:** this topic is actually covered in the "[SQL Antipatterns](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns)", which I strongly recommend you read</sub>

I am a lazy person, which means that I tend to apply [YANGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) to my code. So this is my approach.

So. Let's assume that there are two groups of products:

```
ProductFoo       ProductBar
 - productID      - productID
 - name           - name
 - price          - price
 - color          - supply
 - weight         - manufacturerID
                  - safety
```

In this case there are three common elements, that go in the main `Products` table. And the custom parameters would be stored using *table inheritance* (it's a thing, google it). So, basically you would end up with three tables: `Products`, `ProductsFoo` and `ProductsBar`, where `Products` table has a `"type"` field and both of the "child tables" would have a `productID` foreign key, that's pointing to its parent table.

That's if you know at the development time, what "custom fields" each client will want.

**Now, lets assume clients are being difficult and want make up custom fields whenever they feel like it.**

In this case I would simply create a `Products.data` fields, which contains a JSON with all the custom attributes for each product. And only "extract" special attributes to an inheriting table, when client wants to search by that custom attribute (there is not sane way to index JSON, if clients want to search by their new "wallywanker" attribute).

You end up with same basic structure, but the "sub-tables" only contain the attributes, that are expected to be searchable

I hope this made sense.

Answer (score -2):

If its is a company project, follow the standards followed on previous projects.

Have a look at conventions such as Hungarian notation, that would make more sense than repeating a prefix. Also it is more likely your model name is your table name.

Also if you are planning to use ORM they might have some best practices as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation